# Crash on iOS 13 devices related to NSClassFromString

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

I am getting crash on iOS13 devices with a following crash log

```
Crashed: BSXPCCnx:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices (BSCnx:client:com.apple.frontboard.workspace-service)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS 0x0000000104a1c458
```

App has Firebase, Facebook and Realm SDK which uses NSClassFromString. 96% crashes have occurred when app is in the background state.

We used NSFileProtectionComplete for data protection

One solution suggested on Apple Forum is, if **NSFileProtectionComplete** in entitlements, use **NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication**, then locking specific directories with **NSFileProtectionComplete**. But not sure this solution will work or not as not able to reproduce the crash. Any help will be really appreciated

[image]

Comment: it's may be nsfileprotectioncomplete, change nsfileprotection to none for cache and temp directory and for public files (analytics, logs e.t.c)

Comment: @DmitryCoolerov Thanks. The main concern is I am not able to reproduce the crash. Hence don't know the applied solution is correct or not. Can't send app update with possible solution so checking for confirm/correct solution.

Comment: @miOS I am facing exactly the same issue. Once if I find an answer will let you know. Please update once if you find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428831/crash-foundation-nsclassfromstring200-in-ios-13

Comment: @HarikarthickK sure. Are you able to reproduce the crash?

Comment: When uploading image I just lock my phone and rotate for 15mins then I open it display from the start screen, not the uploading screen. But I can't see any crashes related to my device but it's restarted if I follow these steps.

Comment: @miOS do not attach debugger, rotate phone while blocked

Comment: @miOSDid you find any solution?

Comment: @DmitryCoolerov We have only Portrait orientation for app. Also, tested by not attaching the debugger.

Comment: @HarikarthickK Comment on Apple Forum - Just heard back from Apple DTS.  The Data Protection entitlement issues are fixed in iOS 13.2 Beta 3.  I can no longer reproduce the issue. Hope it will solve. Checking the official documentation. Let me know if you found any official document.

Comment: Sure @miOS. I will check and let you know.

Comment: @miOS we can't find official document for iOS 13.2 beta 3, please share it here.

Comment: Can you please follow the same procedure and update:

1. When the app is running, lock the phone
2. Do mobile call and receive on the device
3. The app goes to the background and crashes.
 
The crash is 100% reproduciable

Comment: @HarikarthickK The comment (steps to reproduce) was added by me on Apple Forum :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With iOS 13.2 beta 3, the crash is not reproducible with above-mentioned step. Looks like the issue was from Apple and they have taken care in 13.2 release

Comment: Verified the crash report and we have not observed above crash on iOS 13.2 version.

Comment: We are getting "NSClassFromString" crash in iOS 15.