# Crash :Foundation NSClassFromString+200 in iOS 13

Tags: ios, firebase, crash, ios13, google-fabric

We have released the latest build with the minimum deployment target 10.We are getting the same many crashes in iOS 13 related to the background issues. 
We are enabling the following capabilities:

> 1.background fetch
>
> 2.push notification(FireBase)
>
> 3.data protection as NSFileProtectionComplete.

When checking the link : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122858 Most answers are switching to  NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication from NSFileProtectionComplete. Is this correct fix?

```
1.Crashed: com.apple.runningboardservices.background-workloop

StackTrace:
dyld3::closure::ObjCStringTable::hash(char const*, unsigned long) const + 16


2.Crashed: com.apple.runningboardservices.connection.incoming

StackTrace:
dyld3::closure::ObjCStringTable::hash(char const*, unsigned long) const + 16


3. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

StackTrace:
dyld3::closure::ObjCStringTable::hash(char const*, unsigned long) const + 16
```

> Note: We are not getting any crashes in iOS 12 below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS 13.2 beta 3, the crash is not reproducible. Looks like the issue was from Apple and they have taken care in 13.2 release

Comment: Hi @miOS, We have followed the same steps but can't able to reproduce

1. When the app is running, lock the phone 
2. Do mobile call and receive on the device 
3. The app goes to the background and crashes. The crash is 100% reproducible

Note: The app gets crashed or it gets restarted? because when we tried the above scenario app get restarted.

Comment: @HarikarthickK The device suppose to have password enabled. Is password enabled?

Comment: @HarikarthickK The app gets restarted means it's crashed and a new instance of app has started. You see a log in Crashlytics if integrated. Your app was restarted means it crashed when it going to background.